# Attach certain files

Tags: excel, email-attachments, vba

I want to build the following:

- select sheets for pdf printing - works
- create folder and print sheets - works
- attach those printed files to an email - doesn't work

the filename depends on cell values + Date (last Range.Value in filename), is there a way to get those pdfs attached?

I tried the following, but that doesn't work

```
'code ...


Dim myDir as String, mySht as String

myDir = "C:\Users\ihlin\OneDrive\Düngung\" & Worksheets("Drip_Drain_Eingabe").Range("s13").Text
mySht = Worksheets("Druckansicht_mmol").Range("c2").Text & "_" & Worksheets("Druckansicht_mmol").Range("K2").Text & "_" & Worksheets("Druckansicht_mmol").Range("P2").Text & "_" & "mmol_" & Worksheets("Druckansicht_mmol").Range("T1").Text

`code ... ...

If CheckBox1 = True Then
.Attachments.Add myDir & "\" & mySht & ".pdf"
End if

If CheckBox2 = True Then
.Attachments.Add myDir & "\" & mySht2 & ".pdf"

If CheckBox1 = True Then
.Attachments.Add myDir & "\" & mySht3 & ".pdf"
End if

If CheckBox1 = True Then
.Attachments.Add myDir & "\" & mySht4 & ".pdf"
End if
```

Publishing takes forever and ends with crashing Excel.
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: what is the last With statement prior to your posted code?

Comment: The last With statement is:

Comment: With xEmailObj
        .Display
        .To = ""
        .cc = ""
        .Subject = "Düngeempfehlung"

Comment: If so you are writing xEmailObj.Display.attachments.add . Perhaps you should be writing xEmailObj.Attachments,add ?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple debugging method. Try the following:

`.Attachments.Add "c:\somehardcoded\address\ofthe\worksheet\folder\file.pdf"`

If it works, then super, you simply have to find a way to represent the folder.
If it does not work, then forget it and try to attach the file in another way.

Comment: Since the filenames are variable I entered the ranges of the corresponding mySht-strings, which again left me with a stuck publishing progress.